# AlarmManager: preventing unwanted job trigger

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I want to show my problem by an example:

I set a RTC_wakeup repeating to 10am that triggers an IntentService, When I run my application in 9:30am it waits until 10am and triggers the service (Great!).

But when I run my application at 10:30, It determines that the scheduled time has passed so it triggers the service (not what i want).

I just want my service to be triggered every day **just once**, exactly at 10am, what should I do? (The problem is whenever application runs after 10am it triggers the service)

here is my code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
    Intent service = new Intent(context, ServiceFTP_LogFileUpload.class);
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, service);

}

public void setAlarm(Context context) {

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    /* Set the alarm to start at 10:00 AM */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {

    // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
    if (alarmMgr!= null) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }

}
```

}

And the alarm is set in SplashScreen (Launcher activity):

```
AlarmReceiver alarm = new AlarmReceiver();
alarm.setAlarm(this);
```